# Comparing two similar pictures to get similarity value

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, similarity, google-vision

I am trying to create my own app and I need to compare two pictures.

A bit of clarification.

- Picture will contain a symbol written on a piece of paper.
- I will have the "Original" picture of piece of paper with symbol on it.
- I need to compare newly captured picture of symbol to the Original picture and determine that if they are both same picture of same symbol.
- The newly captured picture of symbol could be taken from a different angle.

I looked at OpenCV and Google Vision , but I am a bit lost, on how to do it.

My Question

I have the "Original" picture like this

[image: Original]

I have newly captured picture with same symbol on it, but take from a different angle, like this

[image: comparing]

I need to determine if they are "same"(similar) or they are different.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Any clues as to what the other symbols might look like? Or how many there are? Are you planning on continuing with the unhelpful background? Do the backgrounds vary? Is the size completely insignificant so a small star is similar to a large one? Is the colour significant, i.e. is a blue star similar to a red one?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Got no clues, the symbol could be random, like a doodle. There will be only one symbol. The background could be random and vary. But the "Originals" and comparison backgrounds should be the same. The size should matter, but I think it will vary, because of the angle of the 'newly captured picture". Colour should stay the same, but is okay if it doesn't detect color difference . The main goal is to recognize that the "newly captured photo" is the similar to "Original" (on the same background, on the same surface) .

Comment: See you on siamese networks: https://becominghuman.ai/siamese-networks-algorithm-applications-and-pytorch-implementation-4ffa3304c18

Comment: Hey @Nuzhny will this neural network work with only 2 pictures. No test sample. ? Because i cant know what symbols are available, because they can be random. Thus i cant train network to recognize similar stuff.